# What are ways to reduce sleep time?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rests

Being a prepared caster is a lot of work. Sleeping is a cheap natural solution to recover. Sleeping 8 hours is difficult when you are in a rush. I am looking to occasionally reduce sleep time. The obvious solution is the mighty [Ring of Sustenance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance/):

> This ring continually provides its wearer with life-sustaining nourishment. The ring also refreshes the body and mind; its wearer needs only sleep 2 hours per day to gain the benefit of 8 hours of sleep. This allows a spellcaster that requires rest to prepare spells to do so after only 2 hours, but this does not allow a spellcaster to prepare spells more than once per day. The ring must be worn for a full week before it begins to work. If it is removed, the owner must wear it for another week to reattune it to himself.

This ring is based on the [Create Food and Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-food-and-water) spell. This spell only talks about food and water, but I guess that this spell is the nearest spell with the desired effect.

Beside the ring, are there others ways to reduce sleep time? Otherwise, I guess I can create a potion (for example) based on the [Create Food and Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-food-and-water) spell with similar effect as the ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 9 ways I know of

*All links are to PFSRD, the original sources are in brackets.*

### Nap Stack

[Advanced Player’s Guide]

[This cleric or oracle spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/nap-stack/) (3rd level) is extremely potent for sleep reduction as you can also get additional benefits in the same day for more sleep.

> You reduce the amount of uninterrupted sleep or rest creatures within the spell’s area need ... to 2 hours instead of the normal eight ... every additional 2 hours counts as a day of rest

### Spherewalker

[Pathfinder 2: The Skinsaw Murders]

[This prestige class](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/spherewalker/) gives you access to Efficient Sleep at 2nd level and isn't too difficult to pick up (but will require some less than perfect feats for a wizard).

> at 2nd level, a spherewalker ... only needs 4 hours of sleep

### Restful Armor

[Advanced Class Guide]

[This armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/restful/) is just as good as the ring of sustenance for sleep reduction AND you get the added benefit of not becoming fatigued for sleeping in armor.

> reduce the amount of uninterrupted sleep or rest she needs from 8 hours to 2 hours, and the wearer does not become fatigued by sleeping in this armor.

### Verdant Sorcerer

[Advanced Player's Guide]

Multiclass into sorcerer and acquire 3 levels of the [Verdant Sorcerer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/verdant-bloodline/) bloodline to receive the Photosynthesis power.

> At 3rd level, you feed upon nature’s raw essence. Your need to eat and sleep is reduced as if wearing a ring of sustenance

### Monk Unchained

[Pathfinder Unchained]

Multiclass into [this unchained class](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained/) and pick up Ki Metabolism at level 4 for your Ki Power option.

> As long as he has at least 1 point remaining in his ki pool, the monk... needs only 2 hours of sleep each night

### Restful Birch

[Ultimate Wilderness]

Grow a few of [these trees](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-plants/) near your wizards tower and learn to make some tea.

> When a creature consumes a piece of the bark, it reduces the amount of sleep it needs that night by 2 hours (to a minimum of 6 hours)... A piece of bark brewed into a tea reduces the amount of sleep the imbiber needs by 4 hours (to a minimum of 4 hours).

### Dreamer's Star

[Heroes of the Wild]

An herbalist can brew up some tea from [this flower](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances/) which reduces the amount of sleep up to six people need to 6 hours.

> this tea grants the drinker the benefits of a full 8 hours of uninterrupted sleep in only 6 hours. One dose of dreamer’s star makes enough tea to serve six.

### Light Sleeper

[Pathfinder Player Companion: Blood of the Elements]

[This regional trait](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances/) allows you to...

> sleep only 4 hours to get a full night’s rest (restoring 1 hit point per character level).

### Awakened from Stasis

[Pathfinder Player Companion: People of the Stars]

Another regional trait ([this one](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/awakened-from-stasis/) with a much more specific situation) . It's more effective than light sleeper but comes with a side effect of memory loss.

> As a side effect of your stasis, you gain all the benefits of 8 hours of sleep in only 2 hours.

---

There is one more way but it requires a bit of luck and/or DM assistance:

### Reincarnate

A friendly druid, shaman, or witch can kill and [reincarnate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate/) you until you are either [Duergar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/races/duergar/) with the Waking Dreamer alternative racial trait or [Elan](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/races/elan/) [both in Psionics Unleashed] each of which meditate for 4 hours instead of sleep for 8 hours.

> You do not need to sleep at all and can meditate, fully awake and aware, for 4 hours to gain all the benefits of sleep

Comment: The reincarnate one was unexpected! In fact, I am a Kensai Magus. Drinking tea is flavorful. It will be my choice. Thank you!

Comment: you could add this as well: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance/

Comment: @ruedi the OP asked for "other ways" and already mentioned the ring